# Travis-CI does not add deploy section

Tags: travis-ci

I followed the Travis-CI documentation, to creating multiple [deployments](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/script/), and for [notifications](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/).

So this is my config: (the end has `deploy` and `notifications`)

```
sudo: required # is required to use docker service in travis

language: node_js

node_js:
  - 'node'

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - npm install -g yarn --cache-min 999999999
  - "/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_99.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16"

# Use yarn for faster installs
install:
  - yarn

# Init GUI
before_script:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3 # give xvfb some time to start

script:
  - npm run test:single-run

cache:
  yarn: true
  directories:
     - ./node_modules

before_deploy:
  - npm run build:backwards
  - docker --version
  - pip install --user awscli # install aws cli w/o sudo
  - export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin # put aws in the path

deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: scripts/deploy.sh ansyn/client-chrome.v.44 $TRAVIS_COMMIT
    on:
      branch: travis
  - provider: script
    script: scripts/deploy.sh ansyn/client $TRAVIS_TAG
    on:
      tags: true

notifications:
  email: false
```

But this translates to (in Travis - view config): no deploy, no notifications

```
{
  "sudo": "required",
  "language": "node_js",
  "node_js": "node",
  "services": [
    "docker"
  ],
  "before_install": [
    "npm install -g yarn --cache-min 999999999",
    "/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_99.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16"
  ],
  "install": [
    "yarn"
  ],
  "before_script": [
    "export DISPLAY=:99.0",
    "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start",
    "sleep 3"
  ],
  "script": [
    "npm run test:single-run"
  ],
  "cache": {
    "yarn": true,
    "directories": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "before_deploy": [
    "npm run build:backwards",
    "docker --version",
    "pip install --user awscli",
    "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
  ],
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "trusty",
  "os": "linux"
}
```

Comment: It is not displayed in config but the deploy will still run. You can verify this in the job log

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani . I see the `before_deploy`, and `deploying` is empty, like it isn't running it, although clearly I have in my config the deploy script - see https://travis-ci.org/AnSyn/ansyn/jobs/297479879

Comment: Is git repo public? Can I have a look?

Comment: I added a link in the comment above

Comment: Try changing `script: scripts/deploy.sh ansyn/client $TRAVIS_TAG` to `script: sh -x scripts/deploy.sh ansyn/client $TRAVIS_TAG`. This will give a detailed result if the script is being executed or not

Comment: Doing that, and only that, actually worked. It did not built that image, because there is no such image on the machine, which is weird, but at least it ran. Thank you. Please write an answer so I can give you the bounty. https://travis-ci.org/AnSyn/ansyn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158255/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-amit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
script: scripts/deploy.sh ansyn/client $TRAVIS_TAG
```

to

```
script: sh -x scripts/deploy.sh ansyn/client $TRAVIS_TAG
```

This will give a detailed result if the script is being executed or not. Also I looked into the build after those changes. It fails on below

```
Step 4/9 : COPY ./dist /opt/ansyn/app
```

You need to change your deploy section to

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: sh -x scripts/deploy.sh ansyn/client-chrome.v.44 $TRAVIS_COMMIT
    skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      branch: travis
  - provider: script
    script: sh -x scripts/deploy.sh ansyn/client $TRAVIS_TAG
    skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      tags: true
```

So that the `dist` folder is there during deploy and not cleaned up